# How to keep flink logs for long time?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I am using apache flink 1.11.3 for running my java pipelines. I have noticed that failed job are getting cleaned from the history after few hrs. Can we have any parameter regarding this to retained failed/completed task history for at least 7-10 days?

Comment: use state-backend

Comment: @AFarmanbar , I have already configured below state-backend in config file:

state.backend: rocksdb
state.checkpoints.dir: file:///opt/flink/checkpoints/